# Is there a unique saddle value for a convex/concave optimization?

Tags: convex-optimization, convex-analysis

Here is the question:

> Consider a function of two variables $f(x,y)$ on some compact domain. Let it be convex in $x$ and concave in $y$. Is it true that $f(x,y)$ has a uniqe saddle point (stationary point)? Is $(\hat x,\hat y)=\arg \min_x\max_y f(x,y)$, the argument of saddle point, unique?
>   Is there any role of being strictly concave (or convex) in this case?

My guess is that $f(x,y)$ owns a unique saddle point because of the convexity and concavity of the function. I also guess that if the function is strictly concave-convex, then, the argument of the saddle point is also unique.

Any reference for a proof will also suffice. Thx.

Comment: It is not true that there exists a stationary point. If it is not strictly convex/concave, it is not true that the stationary point, when it exists, is unique. And depending on how you define "convexity" for non-convex domains, there may be other obstructions to uniqueness in those cases.

Comment: Let the domain be convex and compact and the function of interest be strictly convex and concave in its arguments. Will the saddle value be unique and if yes I will be happy to see a proof.

Comment: @MichaelGrant yes I mentioned it in the question. I thought I could get a reference there. I dont think that I will get any answer here since the question was asked a few days ago..

Comment: Believe me, I sympathize. But since they migrated it over I am not optimistic you will find an answer. It's still a duplicate, though. Perhaps what you should do is edit the original question to give it this title: it is, after all, a much better title than the generic one you gave it.